# tOracleInput not triggering OnSubjobError, only OnComponentError?

Tags: talend

tOracleInput not triggering `OnSubjobError`, only `OnComponentError`?
For example, if the View/Table doesn’t exist, an error gets logged in the console (cf. below), but `OnSubjobError` doesn’t get executed.

```
Exception in component tOracleInput_1
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:74) ….
```

But if I use `OnComponentError`, then the error is handled correctly. I can’t find any reason why this is so in the documentation, so that is why I ask it here.

[image]

As you can see from the picture, I have to place `OnComponentError` connections (red drawn line) because `OnSubjobError` doesn't do its work. Up till now, I wasn't able to isolate the problem.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your job please?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR screenshot added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just mucked around a bit to try and reproduce this and it seems that because the component in error is a lookup rather than a main part of the flow then it doesn't error the subjob (it simply doesn't use it as an input lookup to the tMap).

Obviously, using an `OnComponentError` link will correctly call the error process.

It's possible to have multiple `OnComponentError` flows going into the same component so you can have them all pointing to the same process/subjobs without having to copy the resulting subjobs and then maintain them separately - although this would be a good candidate for using a joblet if you wished to have them separately and reduce the amount of spaghetti flows in your job.

Comment: Seems you are right. Check this out: https://jira.talendforge.org/browse/TDI-19465

Comment: Watched and voted for that jira item. It is a bit inconsistent and not obvious/expected behaviour.